# Why won't my drive boot over FireWire?

Tags: macos, boot, external-hard-drive, firewire, mac-pro

I have a brand new [Western Digital MyPassport Studio](http://wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=420), which I'd like to use as a utility drive. It will boot my **Mac Pro** over USB, but not over FireWire 800. Western Digital's support basically told me it's not their problem, although their [knowledge base article](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1787/~/list-of-mac-bootable-wd-external-drives-and-how-to-format-them-to-install-on) states that the drive should boot an Intel Mac over FireWire.

It's partitioned like so (using GUID):

- Partition A: 12 GB, HFS+ Journaled
- Partition B: 63 GB, FAT
- Partition C: 925 GB, HFS+ Journaled (the remainder, rounded)

I installed Lion on Partition A, so it's now 11.5 GB, after the Recovery HD partition took its share. I've tried booting holding down Option, and neither Partition A or Recovery HD show up, though both do with USB.

Also, when it's plugged in with FW800, Partition A does show up in the Startup preference pane. When I select it and restart, though, it spends a long time before the Apple logo shows up, and I end up booted to my default, internal disk.

I tried plugging directly into the front FW800 port, and also through other (LaCie) drives daisy chained to a rear port, and that made no difference.

This is very frustrating, and would potentially make me return the drive if I can't find a solution. What could be causing this?

Comment: Check - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2699 - do you have built-in FireWire ports?

Comment: Do Western Digital say it should boot off Firewire and it is just your set up?

Comment: @ChrisF it's a Mac Pro

Comment: @Mark According to a WD support article, the drive should be bootable on an Intel Mac through FireWire: http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1787/~/list-of-mac-bootable-wd-external-drives-and-how-to-format-them-to-install-on

Comment: I would format run dusk utility and verify it over firewire or even reformat it over firewire

Comment: @Mark I've already reformatted several times over FireWire.